# Why I can't use "tupled" of case class when I add companion object?

Tags: scala, case-class

When I add companion object to my case class I can't use tupled to pass parameters as a tuple.

```
case class Person(name:String, age:Int)
object Person {}

Person.tupled // Not works
```

**Error:**

```
Error:(7, 9) value tupled is not a member of object A$A6.this.Person
Person.tupled
       ^
```

Some one can explain this behavior? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For automatically synthesized case class companion objects, `tupled` is inherited from `FunctionN`. However, you *explicitly* told Scala that you want your companion object to *not* inherit from `FunctionN`, ergo, you don't get `tupled`.

Answer (score 2):

Since `tupled` method is [Function2](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/Function2.html#tupled:((T1,T2))=>R)'s method,

You can achieve this by `val f: ((String, Int)) => Person = (Person.apply _).tupled`.

Comment: I tried your solution it gives an error as "implementation restricts functions to 22 parameters".

Comment: @AdityaJain seems your `entity` has more than 22 parameters,  for **Scala** now, **case entity** support more than *22* parameters, but for `Tuple` and `Function` still have a limitation for **22** parameters. so when `tupled` to `Function`, will failed on this.